# Setup a TMS layer in OpenLayers mobile

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, tms

Is it possible to use a TMS layer when using OpenLayers.mobile?

I did console.dir(OpenLayers.Layer) and cannot see TMS listed as it is with standard OpenLayers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that this can be achieved using the non-stable code via github. Check the development on github and clone using git.